# how to decode multiple objects from data stored in file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a form with information first name and last name and some other information. I use a person class to store this information. on submit click I archiving it in a file person.txt using NSCoding implemented in person class. if I add multiple persons in the file person.txt, how can I get all the person objects stored in the file. decoding the person class just gives me the last added person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all of the person objects serialized, then you need the `NSArray` or whatever other collection class in which they are stored to be the root object for the `NSKeyedArchiver`.  e.g.: (assumes ARC)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person:NSObject <NSCoding>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *firstName;
// etc.
@end

@implementation Person

@synthesize lastName = _lastName;
@synthesize firstName = _firstName;

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.lastName forKey:@"ln"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.firstName forKey:@"fn"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) { return nil; }

    _lastName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ln"];
    _firstName = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"fn"];

    return self;
}

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Person *me = [Person new];
    me.lastName = @"Kitten";
    me.firstName = @"Mittens";

    Person *you = [Person new];
    you.lastName = @"Youe";
    you.firstName = @"JoJo";

    NSArray *people = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:me,you,nil];
    NSData *serializedData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:people];

    //  write your serializedData to file, etc.

    [p release];
}
```

Why the .txt extension on your archive, though?  It just binary data, right?